# Is it possible to postpone the value of a property but use it before?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var oHelper = {
  ref: null,
  data: {"key":"value"}
}
var oSettingsThing = {
  data: oHelper.ref,
  //....
}

//....some lines before or in other file loaded after
$(document).ready(function() {
  oHelper.ref = doDataStuff( oHelper.data );
  var thing = Framework.crate('module.thing', oSettingsThing );
}
```

My purpose is to keep `$(document).ready(function(){` as clean as possible, and if it's possible, to separate both blocks in separated files.

I thought that as in variable copying in setting properties values the copy by reference will help me, but I was wrong and on `Framework.crate('module.thing', oSettingsThing );` the value of `oHelper.ref`is still `null`.

What do not I understand?

I'm using ExtJs and the objects structure it's quite more complex:

```
var oHelper = {
  ref: null,
  data: {"key":"value"}
}
//....
var oSettingsThing = {
GENERALS:{
    //..
    items: [
        {
            items: [
                {
                    //....
                    store: oHelper.ref,
                }
//.... 
Ext.onReady(function() {

  mc_documentos.stores.STATUS.ref = new Ext.data.SimpleStore(mc_documentos.stores.STATUS.data );
  //I was hopping to at this point have oSettingsThing.GENERALS...data !== null
  var generalsFilters= Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', oSettingsThing.GENERALS );
```

Comment: Primitive values are copied. `null` is a primitive value. But even if you'd have an empty object at the beginning `data` would get reference to that object, not to the `oHelper.ref` property.

Comment: _Primitive values are copied._ this is what i didn't know, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

On execution `oSettingsThing.data` will point to `null`. It will not be linked to `oHelper.ref`.

Now if you do this:

```
var oHelper = {
  ref: null
};
var oSettingsThing = {
  data: oHelper, // point to oHelper instead of oHelpder.ref
};

console.log(oSettingsThing.data.ref); // null
oHelper.ref = "somedata";
console.log(oSettingsThing.data.ref); // "somedata"
```

Comment: As i said to @Adder i'm ommitting the framework i'm using because is not relevant, but i can't do `data: oHelper`, the objects are quite more complex.

I hace to do `oHelper.ref = doDataStuff( oHelper.data );` but maybe `data`and `ref`could be in different objects.

Answer (score 0):

`null` is a kind of reference, and when it is assigned to `oSettingsThing.data` `null` is being assigned.

You could do

```
var thing = Framework.create('module.thing', oHelper.ref );
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you assign something to `oHelper.ref`, the previous value is detached from the symbol (not destroyed, because `oSettingsThing.data` still points to it).

Consider making `oHelper.ref` an object itself:

```
var oHelper = {
    ref: { value: null }
}

var oSettingsThing = {
    data: oHelper.ref
}

// later
oHelper.ref.value = something_else;

oSettingsThing.data.value // something_else
```

If you can't change the structure of `oSettingsThing`:

```
oSettingsThing.data = oHelper.ref = doDataStuff( oHelper.data );
```

Comment: I'cant modify `oSettingsThing` structure, so i' cant do `oSettingsThing.data.value`.

Comment: @buguibu Then, `oSettingsThing.data = oHelper.ref = doDataStuff( oHelper.data );` perhaps? :)

Comment: That works, but it is  not what i'm looking for, because the strcuture is very more complex that i have post. What you said it's translated in my code to this ugly line `mc_documentos.filters.GENERALS.items[0].items[0].store = mc_documentos.stores.COMMUNITY.ref = new Ext.data.SimpleStore( mc_documentos.stores.COMMUNITY.data );` and i want to avoid it.

Comment: @buguibu I understand, but without modifying your structure, that's what you would be looking at ... unless of course `oHelper.ref` is already properly initialized when you define `oSettingsThing`.